# Changing DataFrame with .apply() depending on NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I'd like to replace every NaN value in my data frame with a 1 and every other value with a 0. It's just an example for a project where I need to change the df depending on the NaN value in one column.

I tried isnull(), isnan(), x.Field_2 and many more variations. Also the documentation of isnull didn't really help me. I googled a lot and only found operations where I can get all NaN values of a df.

I guess the problem is that x['Field_2'].isnull() is returning an array but I couldn't think of something else that would change the df. Basically I'm searching for a a way to check for every row if the cell is NaN and execute it for every cell.

My error message:

```
KeyError: 'Field_2'
```

```
# importing pandas and numpy libraries 
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

# creating and initializing a nested list 
values_list = [[15, 2.5, np.nan], [20, 4.5, 50], [25, 5.2, 80], 
            [45, 5.8, 48], [40, np.nan, 70], [41, 6.4, 90], 
            [51, 2.3, 111]] 

# creating a pandas dataframe 
df = pd.DataFrame(values_list, columns=['Field_1', 'Field_2', 'Field_3'], 
                index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']) 

df = df.apply(lambda x: 1 if x['Field_2'].isnull() else 0)
```

--------- solution

Through your help I could solve my problem. Thanks a lot! - final solution:

```
resultList = df.apply(lambda x: x['Field_1'] if pd.isna(x['Field_2']) else x['Field_2'], axis=1) 

df['newColumn'] = resultList
df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think here loops are not necessary use [`DataFrame.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) with convert to integers for `True/False` to `1/0` mapping:

```
df = df.isna().astype(int) 
print (df)

   Field_1  Field_2  Field_3
a        0        0        1
b        0        0        0
c        0        0        0
d        0        0        0
e        0        1        0
f        0        0        0
g        0        0        0
```

Your solution should be changed with `axis=1` for loop per rows and for test scalars is used [`pandas.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.isna.html):

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: 1 if pd.isna(x['Field_2']) else 0, axis=1)
```